# An example of Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I'm a bit confused. So first it says that $z_0 = -i$ and $z^2-4z+4=(z-2)^2$ is a point within the circle C, which means at $z=i$ the function $f$ is not analytic. Then it says that f is analytic at all points within and on the contour C. I mean how is it analytic at $z=i$ which is also in C?

Comment: $f(z) = z^2-4z+4$ is a polynomial, and analytic in all of $\Bbb C$. Where do you read that $f$ is not analytic at $z=i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CIF says $f(z)=\frac 1 {2\pi i}\int_C \frac {f(\zeta)} {\zeta-z}d\zeta$ if $f$ is analytic inside  and on $C$. Here $f(z)=z^{2}-4z+4$.

Comment: Yes of course, got confused for a sec, thanks